# gunicorn and Django project

Tags: django, gunicorn

I just followed instructions from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). After:

```
 sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 nameofmyproject.wsgi:application
```

bind Gunicorn my site is not available.I tried to change port from 8000 to 80 (i type mysite.com:8000 and is not working...), and then site is reachable, but without any static files like css and images. Don't know why this happens.

```
sudo ss -naptu state listening | grep :80
```

Output is:

```
tcp    0      128            *:8000                       *:*                   users:(("gunicorn",pid=18461,fd=5),("gunicorn",pid=18455,fd=5))
```

What can I do? It's my first deploy so I would be very grateful for really simple instructions...

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to `8000`, the site will be available on port 8000, e.g. `http://server_domain_or_IP:8000` (just like it was when you tried `manage.py runserver` earlier in the tutorial.

> then site is reachable, but without any static files like css and images

The tutorial explains that `gunicorn` is not handling static files. That will be done by nginx later. You are seeing the expected behaviour, so you can carry on with the tutorial.

Next, the tutorial changes gunicorn to use a socket file instead of port 8000, then finally it configures Nginx to proxy pass to gunicorn using the socket file. At this point you will see your site, including the static files.

Comment: The problem is that http://www.mysite.whatev:8000 IS NOT reachable. I know nginx is for static files. But things stop here. I can't go to my site from now on :/

Comment: If you could access the site on `mysite.whatev:8000` when you did `runserver`, then you should be able to access the site on port 8000 when running gunicorn. If it didn't work with runserver, then perhaps you missed out the firewall steps of the tutorial. In any case, the next step is to change gunicorn to use a sock file rather than using port 8000, so it doesn't really matter if you can't access the site on port 8000.

Comment: I didin't skip firewall thing (or if it is necessary to do something more than `sudo ufw allow 8000`)... And i can't connect to my site unless i runserver on 0.0.0.0:80. Even with 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: If `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` doesn't work either, then you've got a firewalling issue, not an issue with gunicorn. I can't help you with that. But as I've already explained, it doesn't really matter if you can't access the site on page 8000 because that's not the final configuration. You can carry on with the tutorial.

Comment: I can't carry out the tutorial. How it will work if even simple server run finishes in fail ?

Comment: My explanations don’t seem to be helping , but I’ll try one last time. The server run works, since you can access it when you run in on port 80. It sounds like a firewall is preventing you from accessing the server when you run it on port 8000. I can’t help you do with that firewall issue. However, the rest of the tutorial doesn’t use port 8000, so you can carry on to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

```
manage.py runserver
```

It's only for development, if you want to run it on production, you have to use something like nginx and gunicorn

```
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=vbaddict
Group=vbaddict
WorkingDirectory=/...../
ExecStart=/...../bin/gunicorn --bind=127.0.0.1 --timeout 120 --workers 1 --bind unix:/.../application.sock project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name carius.vbaddict.net;
    access_log  /var/log/.../.log;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/..../application.sock;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
    }
}
```

It's a small example

And it you need a static file, you just need to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```